# is it possible to change the shipping address on an order on shopify

Tags: shopify

I want to change the shipping address after an order has been submitted. Is this possible, I have been looking for ways to do this but it seems like no one has ever had this issue... I wish to do this via an API call. I want my customers to be able to change their shipping address of their order.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible with API call.

Using shopify Order API call to [update order](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#update). Look for an example below

```
PUT => /admin/orders/#{id}.json

{
  "order": {
    "id": 450789469,
    "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "address1": "123 Fake Street",
      "phone": "777-777-7777",
      "city": "Fakecity",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "country": "Canada",
      "zip": "K2P 1L4"
     }
  }
}
```

This should update your order.

*Note : haven't tested this but while creating order, it works exactly this way.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking as an admin, head to https://YOURSTORENAME.myshopify.com/admin/orders then select the order in question, on the right hand panel you should see the shipping address, from there hit edit and you can change the address.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I wish to do this with an API call.